# u-green USB Audio in the Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, xubuntu

I've got an u-green USB audio card. When I've plugged it into my Xubuntu 20.04 box nothing happened, it is not available as audio output/input device. `lsusb` shows me following entry:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
```

Can please anyone help me about how to get that working.
Note: the same device works good in Windows.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? The device seems to be recognized. Have you checked you sound settings looking for a new device? Please do.

Comment: I expect it at least to appear in the audio mixer. But it is not.

Comment: Which "audio mixer" exactly? If you're thinking `alsmixer` that depends on pulseaudio and usually sees the audio device currently selected. How does it appear in system settings?

Comment: Not sure where to look for that. I'm using Xubuntu and surprisingly I could not find anything audio related in the system settings. I also tried to look at output of `aplay -l` it shows usb audio card as card #1. in `alsamixer` I could switch to it and even change volume but still there is no sound. I am checking by trying to play a youtube video in the firefox.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Xubuntu.

Comment: Except volume control utility. But the device is not listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Following has helped me:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and reboot after that.

The cause is said to be kernel regression.

[source](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)